# show error message if code not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of Ip addresses belonging to switches and i am using snmpwalk on that array of ip addresses.
if i was to unplug one switch then the ip address corresponding to that switch in the array will not execute.The ip address will still be present in the array it just won't be able to execute. How would i write up a code to show an error/echo error massage if this happens but still execute the other ip addresses?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'name');

$results   = array();
$secondRow = array();

foreach ($switchArray as $key => $value) {

    $results = snmpwalk($value, "public", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1");

    foreach ($results as $secondResults) {
        $secondResults = str_replace(" ", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("Hex-STRING:", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("STRING:", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("INTEGER:", "", $secondResults);

        $secondArray[] = $secondResults;

    }


}

echo "looping through results of the ip";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($secondArray);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`snmpwalk`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.snmpwalk.php) returns `false` on failure, so you could just check for that value first and log/echo the error then `continue` the array iteration.

```
<?php
$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'name');

$results   = array();
$secondRow = array();

foreach ($switchArray as $key => $value) {

    $results = snmpwalk($value, "public", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1");

    // check for error and continue
    if (false === $results) {
        echo "$value unreachable <br>".PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($results as $secondResults) {
        $secondResults = str_replace(" ", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("Hex-STRING:", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("STRING:", "", $secondResults);
        $secondResults = str_replace("INTEGER:", "", $secondResults);

        $secondArray[] = $secondResults;

    }


}

echo "looping through results of the ip";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($secondArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank You . This helped. Can i ask what does PHP_EOL do ?

Comment: It's the end of line constant. Will be `\n` on *nix platforms and `\r\n` on Windows